# Filtering the MAX() function in a JOINED MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Solved:  Here is the solution code.**

```
//Extend Category queries to support "latest_post" for orderby parameter
function filter_term_sort_by_latest_post_clauses( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( in_array('category', $taxonomies) && $args['orderby'] == 'latest_post' )
    {
        $pieces['fields'] .= ", MAX(p.post_date) AS last_date";
        $pieces['join'] .= " JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID=tr.object_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id";
        $pieces['where'] .= " AND p.post_status='publish' GROUP BY t.term_id";
        $pieces['orderby'] = "ORDER BY last_date";
        $pieces['order'] = "DESC"; // DESC or ASC
    }
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses', 'filter_term_sort_by_latest_post_clauses', 10, 3);
```

**Original question:**

I have added the following function & filter hook in a WordPress site  that allows me to list the  categories, sorted by the most recent post in each category. The function works as expected, except that draft posts are included, and will move that particular category to the top of the list.

```
//Extend Category queries to support "latest_post" for orderby parameter
function filter_term_sort_by_latest_post_clauses( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( in_array('category', $taxonomies) && $args['orderby'] == 'latest_post' )
    {
        $pieces['fields'] .= ", MAX(p.post_date) AS last_date";
        $pieces['join'] .= " JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID=tr.object_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id";
        $pieces['where'] .= " GROUP BY t.term_id";
        $pieces['orderby'] = "ORDER BY last_date";
        $pieces['order'] = "DESC"; // DESC or ASC
    }
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses', 'filter_term_sort_by_latest_post_clauses', 10, 3);
```

I would like to be make the select clause "MAX(p.post_date) AS last_date"  only include values from published posts ( WHERE p.post_status=publish" )

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: What about adding the statement to where clause: $pieces['where'] .= " WHERE p.post_status='publish' GROUP BY t.term_id"; . Unless i missed something this should be an easy fix. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! As usual I was making it much harder than it needs to be in my head. I needed to use an AND in stead of WHERE in order to not conflict with the existing WHERE clause from the WordPress query.

Comment: Post as an answer and I will mark it as the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: i do not see any where clause - but i saw you added the condition on join. Should work too.

Comment: The where clause is not visible in the above snippet because it is created by WordPress and we are just appending additional text onto that portion of the default query. (notice the .= php operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding the statement to where clause: $pieces['where'] .= " WHERE p.post_status='publish' GROUP BY t.term_id"; . Unless i missed something this should be an easy fix. Hope this helps.

Comment: I needed to use an "AND" instead of "WHERE" in order to not conflict with the existing WHERE clause from the WordPress query. See original post for full code snippet.